# Looking for LINQ expression for foreach loop

Tags: c#

I have 2 device classes,

```
public class Device1
{
    public string DeviceName { get; set; }
    public string IP { get; set; }
    public bool IsExist { get; set; }
}
public class Device2
{
    public string DeviceName { get; set; }
    public string DeviceIP { get; set; }
}
```

The current value for "IsExist" is "false" for "Device1[]" array,

```
private static Device1[] GetDevice1Arr()
    {
        List<Device1> d1List = new List<Device1>() {
            new Device1 { DeviceName="d1", IP="1", IsExist=false},
            new Device1 { DeviceName="d2", IP="1", IsExist=false}
        };

        return d1List.ToArray();
    }
```

Now "Device2[]" array don't having "IsExist",

```
 private static Device2[] GetDevice2Arr()
    {
        List<Device2> d2List = new List<Device2>() {
            new Device2 { DeviceName="d1", DeviceIP="3"},
            new Device2 { DeviceName="d2", DeviceIP="1"},
            new Device2 { DeviceName="d2", DeviceIP="2"},
            new Device2 { DeviceName="d3", DeviceIP="3"}
        };

        return d2List.ToArray();
    }
```

Now I am comparing both array "Device1[]" and "Device2[]" by using 2 "foreach" loop, if DeviceName and DeviceIP is same, I am resetting "IsExist" = "true".

**Looking for LINQ replacement here or any alternate way**. Thanks!

```
Device1[] d1 = GetDevice1Arr();
Device2[] d2 = GetDevice2Arr();

foreach(var device1 in d1)
{
    foreach(var device2 in d2)
    {
        if(device2.DeviceName == device1.DeviceName && device2.DeviceIP == device1.IP)
        {
            device1.IsExist = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace the *inner* `foreach` loop with Linq, but not the *outer* one since Linq is for *querying* not *updating*.  What you have is essentially an `Any` query (does *any* item in `d2` match this condition?):

```
Device1[] d1 = GetDevice1Arr();
Device2[] d2 = GetDevice2Arr();

foreach(var device1 in d1)
{
    device1.IsExist = d2.Any(device2 => 
                             device2.DeviceName == device1.DeviceName 
                          && device2.DeviceIP == device1.IP));
}
```

There may be alternate ways using `Intersect`, `Join`, `Where`, etc. to find the items that need to be updated, but in the end a `foreach` loop is the proper way to update them.

Comment: Negative Voter.. care to explain?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're trying to do a join. You can do that in LINQ, but you'll still need a `foreach` to update `IsExist` on the result:

```
var itemsToUpdate = from d1 in GetDevice1Arr()
                    join d2 in GetDevice2Arr()
                         on new { d1.DeviceName, d1.IP }
                         equals new { d2.DeviceName, IP = d2.DeviceIP }
                    select d1;

foreach(var d1 in itemsToUpdate)
    d1.IsExist = true;
```

Comment: Very nice. The only Version here that made that mess more readable to me than the original. I normally like the dot syntax more. But this really shows the power of SQL-like. :-)

Answer (score 3):

**One liner**

```
d1.Where(dev1=> d2.Any(dev2=>dev2.DeviceName == dev1.DeviceName && 
                             dev2.DeviceIP == dev1.IP))
  .ToList()
  .ForEach(dev1=>dev1.IsExist = true);
```

**Final Output**

```
d1.Dump(); //LinqPad feature
```

[image]

Comment: amazing, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Since both are list(type casted to array), you can use [List.ForEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx) to iterate over first list, and [Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697(v=vs.110).aspx) to iterate over inner list.

```
d1.ForEach( d=> d.IsExist = d2.Any(x => x.DeviceIP == d.IP && x.DeviceName == d.DeviceName);
```

This one, and all other solutions use two level iterations, and are just shorthands to your existing solution. You cannot get away with it.

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion with using a join, but as an emulated 'left' join to get true or false:

```
Device1[] d1 = GetDevice1Arr();
Device2[] d2 = GetDevice2Arr();

foreach(var d in from dev1 in d1
    join dd in d2 on new {dev1.DeviceName, dev1.IP} equals new {dd.DeviceName, IP = dd.DeviceIP} into d3    
    select new {dev1, Exists = d3.Any()})
    d.dev1.IsExist= d.Exists;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  d1.Where(x => d2.Any(y => x.IsExist = (x.DeviceName == y.DeviceName && x.IP == y.DeviceIP))).ToList();
```